# Windows 2012 R2 server on Azure hangs for about 20 minute every week

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, azure, virtual-machines

We have a Windows 2012 R2 server on Azure and it hangs for about 20 minutes every Tuesday morning. When the server is hung, we noticed:

1) Most of the IIS (web) requests are not served.

2) No new Scheduled tasks are starting. They log an error code ‭2147549186‬ in the task history

3) Scheduled tasks that were already started, also hung during this time and resume after 20 minutes.

4) Remote desktop connection prompts for the password, then fails with an error saying "Internal server error has occurred"

5) In the event log there are very few events logged

6) Server responds to ping

7) Based on Micah's comment below: We see very high OS read activity during this time. But not sure what is getting read.

We have even tried resizing the VM and it did not help. Any ideas on how we can troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Did you find any logs in the VM that might give us a direction to look? What seems to happen in the logs leading up to the hang? Does it recover on its own? Also, check the metrics tab in the Azure portal to see if you notice any spikes

Comment: Thanks Micah, We checked the usual suspects for the logs (Event log, Dr Watson etc) and couldn't find anything. After you pointed out, we checked the Azure metrics and found the OS Disk Read operations spike (600/s) compared to the average (50/s). How can we find out what is causing the spike in read operations?

Comment: Looks like a snapshot happening. How large is the server occupied space in GB/TB ?

Comment: The OS drive is about 127GB (which had the highest read), but the rest of the drives are quite large about 6 x 4TB drives. Is there any logs we can check about the snapshot? We do have Azure Backup services backing up the machine, but that happens daily at a different time.

Comment: Also we found a kernel dump captured during the outage and only one suspisicous process in that is the CollectGuestLogs and there is a discussion about this process at https://evotec.xyz/collectguestlogs-exe-high-disk-usage-on-azure-vm/ . Is there anyway to log which processes are using the disk?

Comment: Honestly, I think to investigate this further you might want to open a technical support ticket. We can have out Storage and Backup engineers take a look and help you optimize the process and ensure there is no downtime. If you don't have the ability to open a technical support ticket you can email me at AzCommunity@microsoft.com and provide me with your SubscriptionID and link to this thread. I can enable your subscription for that request.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with CollectGuestLogs.exe or Log agent. I have 2 suggestions that may work.

First, try：

1. Uninstall the agent
2. Remove directory C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics
3. Install agent again

If that doesn't solve it, try the following:

1. Navigate to C:\WindowsAzure, find the most recent "GustAgent" folder and open it.
2. Open a "CommonAgentConfig.config" in a text editor and look for the "enablePushInVMLogs" and set the value to "false".
3. Restart the RDAgent.

Hope this helps.